# Spotify API does not load the data first time in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, spotify

I created a Web App in React JS using Spotify API where a user can add a track to the playlist and save the playlist to Spotify account. Everything works fine but when a user searches for the track it loads the first time and disappears then it works smoothly the second time and so on. Any solution?

Here's the link to Github repo - https://github.com/iharmanpannu/jamming-app

and Link to working Web App - http://high-brothers.surge.sh/

Comment: Might not be a solution to your problem, but I see in https://github.com/iharmanpannu/jamming-app/blob/master/src/Components/App/App.js#L28 (App.addTrack()) that you mutate your state directly. This can cause weird errors like yours.

Unlike .filter(), .push() doesn't create a new array. You should use ES6 spread operator here: let tracks = [...this.state.playlistTracks, track];

Change this and let us know if it works. If it does, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I tried your solution but the problem still exist any another solution you have in mine?